# Get the individual value from a list when the ID is the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the individual value for a list when the ID's are the same because I'm using a foreach loop to generate the list.

Currently I am only able to get the value for the first item the page loads.

No matter what item I click I always get the top value.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="listview lv-user m-t-20">
    <div class="lv-item media">
            <div class="lv-title">test 1</div>  
            <input type="hidden" name="screen_name_test" id="screen_name_test" value="this is test 1"> 
            </div>
    </div>
     <div class="lv-item media">
            <div class="lv-title">test 2</div>  
            <input type="hidden" name="screen_name_test" id="screen_name_test" value="this is test 2"> 
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lv-item media">
            <div class="lv-title">test 3</div>  
            <input type="hidden" name="screen_name_test" id="screen_name_test" value="this is test 3"> 
            </div>
    </div>
```

---

```
$( ".lv-item" ).each(function(index) {
    $(this).on("click", function(){
        alert($('#screen_name_test').attr('value'));
    });
});
```

I have also created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35d8Lu9b/).

Comment: ID should always be unique. use class

Comment: **ID of an element must be unique**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As address by others, problem here is duplicate id. Perhaps you can simply change this line,

```
$('#screen_name_test').attr('value')
```

To this:

```
$(this).find('#screen_name_test').val()
```

To be more precise:

```
$(".lv-item").on("click", function(){
  alert($(this).find('#screen_name_test').val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `children()` event. try

```js
$( ".lv-item" ).each(function(index) {
    $(this).on("click", function(){
        alert($(this).children("#screen_name_test").attr('value'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="listview lv-user m-t-20">
        <div class="lv-item media">
                <div class="lv-title">this is test 1</div>  
                <input type="hidden" name="screen_name_test" id="screen_name_test" value="this is test 1"> 
                </div>
        </div>
         <div class="lv-item media">
                <div class="lv-title">this is test 2</div>  
                <input type="hidden" name="screen_name_test" id="screen_name_test" value="this is test 2"> 
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="lv-item media">
                <div class="lv-title">this is test 3</div>  
                <input type="hidden" name="screen_name_test" id="screen_name_test" value="this is test 3"> 
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change  `id="screen_name_test"`  to  `class="screen_name_test"` then use

```
$( ".lv-item" ).on('click',function() {
    alert($(this).find('.screen_name_test').attr('value'));
});
```

or

```
$( ".lv-item" ).each(function() {
    alert($(this).find('.screen_name_test').attr('value'));
});
```